# Minikube Error "loading cached images: Docker load'

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to start minikube in `Windows 10` using below command. `minikube` version `v1.10.1`

```
minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox --no-vtx-check
```

But i'm getting below error

```
 Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=4096MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
    * Preparing Kubernetes v1.18.2 on Docker 19.03.8 ...
    * Unable to load cached images: loading cached images: Docker load /var/lib/minikube/images/pause_3.2: loadimage docker.: docker load -i /var/lib/minikube/images/pause_3.2: Process exited with status 1
    stdout:

    stderr:
    Error processing tar file(exit status 1): archive/tar: invalid tar header

    *
    * [OOM_KILL_SCP] Failed to update cluster updating node: downloading binaries: NewSession: new client: new client: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:2506->127.0.0.1:2427: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
    * Suggestion: Disable dynamic memory in your VM manager, or pass in a larger --memory value
    * Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1766
```

So i thought of degrading the minikube version. so i used `v1.7.2` version and then `v1.3.0` version but in both cases i got the same above mentioned error. Kindly suggest

Regards

Comment: Could you provide steps you have taken to run minikube? (What did you download and from where, what versions of kubernetes and docker are you using)

Comment: @PjoterS I'm using kutectl version - v1.18.0 and minikube version - v1.10.1 and both from github. Since i'm using Windows 10 Home edition where hyper-v is not supported, so using virtualbox. Docker i'm not running separately. minikube would be having a inbuilt docker. Below is the command used to start minikube
`minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox --no-vtx-check`

Comment: What output you got after using `systeminfo` commad? What is your PC resources (CPU, RAM) in total?

Comment: 8 core CPU and 8 GB RAM i5 processor

Answer (score 1):

It worked. Below are the steps which i have done as part of change for minikube in Windows 10 Home edition where hyper-v is not supported

Step 1: Enable virtualization and install virtualbox

step 2: add kutectl and minikube installer

step 3:

Run below command

```
minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox --memory 4096
```

If it fails then

`minikube delete` and delete .minikube and .kubectl folders

Enable WSL 2

Open PowerShell as Administrator and run:

## Enable WSL1

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
```

## Enable WSL2

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart
```

Restart the system

Install Linux Distribution Package

Click [here](https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi)!

Disable hypervisorlaunchtype

Open CMD

Run bcdedit to check hypervisor status

```
bcdedit
```

If hypervisorlaunchtype is set to auto then disable it:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Reboot

Again run minikube

```
minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox --memory 4096
```